# UnityのPostProcessBuildでXcodeのグループが追加できない

Tags: c#, xcode, unity3d

UnityのビルドをUnityCloudBuildに任せたくてPostProcessBuildでXcodeビルドの設定を自動化しようとしているのですが、Xcodeのグループの追加方法が分かりません。

```
[PostProcessBuild]
public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget,string path){

    CopyAndReplaceDirectory(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "Assets/Plugins/iOS/XXXX",Path.Combine(path,"Classes/XXXX"));
}

internal static void CopyAndReplaceDirectory(string srcPath, string dstPath)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(dstPath))
        Directory.Delete(dstPath);
    if (File.Exists(dstPath))
        File.Delete(dstPath);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(dstPath);

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(srcPath))
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(dstPath, Path.GetFileName(file)));

    foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(srcPath))
        CopyAndReplaceDirectory(dir, Path.Combine(dstPath, Path.GetFileName(dir)));
}
```

上記のコードでAssets/Plugins/iOS/内のXXXというディレクトリをまるごとXcodeProjectのClasses直下にコピーする事は出来るのですが、当然ディレクトリとしてコピーされます。

UnityからXcodeにビルドした後に、Xcode上でClassesに対象ディレクトリを直接ドラッグすると問題なくグループとして追加出来るのですが、その一手間を自動化したいと試行錯誤しているところです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。